# How to use a useState variable for the value of SandpackCodeEditor?

Tags: reactjs, codesandbox

I would like to have a state variable that tracks the value of the code for a SandpackCodeEditor from react-sandpack.

I've followed the instructions [here](https://sandpack.codesandbox.io/docs/getting-started/custom-content) to get this code snippet:

```
export default function App() {

const [code, setCode] = useState(`export default function App() {
  return <h1>Hello World</h1>
}`);

return (
      <SandpackProvider template="react" files={{
        "/App.js": code
      }}>
        <SandpackLayout>
          <SandpackCodeEditor />
          <SandpackPreview />
        </SandpackLayout>
      </SandpackProvider>
)
}
```

However, even though this lets me edit the code in the editor, the value of code does not get updated.

I have also tried to use the 'useActiveCode' hook [here](https://sandpack.codesandbox.io/docs/advanced-usage/hooks#usesandpack), but I don't know how to use it with the SandpackCodeEditor component.

I'm sure I'm missing something very simple here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sandpack-react-9u6k14?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Solved. You can use the [useActiveCode hook](https://sandpack.codesandbox.io/docs/advanced-usage/hooks#useactivecode) for this, I was just being foolish and using the hook wrong, ie

```
const {innercode, updateCode} = useActiveCode;
```

rather than

```
const {code, updateCode} = useActiveCode;
```